# How can I get this value out of my json result?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jquery-1.5

I am using jquery and I am return a json result from my asp.net mvc controller.

It comes back like this

```
{"Errors":{"key1":"afkafk"},"IsValid":false,"SuccessMessage":""}
```

how do I get the value of "key1"?

I tried to do

```
var ajax = $.ajax({...});
ajax.success(function(response)
{
   alert(response.Errors.key1);
});
```

this however just prints out [object,Object]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be right.

This implies that that is in fact not how the JSON comes back at all. Stringify response to find out for sure: `alert(JSON.stringify(response));`.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - That would just print out the whole json as a string? I want to access keys in the "Errors" and get the values from them when I call its key up.

Comment: @chobo2: Yes, I know what you are trying to do. As I said, something is wrong with your input as your code is ok, so use the code I showed you to verify that input is what you think it is.

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal   - Looks the same how it looks in firebug {"Errors":{"key1":"afkafk"},"IsValid":false,"SuccessMessage":""}

Comment: @chobo2: I cannot explain that behaviour. As I said, your code looks right.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  - Hmm I think it might be working now. I restarted the browser cleared cache and now it seems to work.

Comment: @chobo2 The default HTTP Method for jquery.ajax is GET, and Browsers cache GET Requests. So if you changed your MVC Controller without clearing your browser cache, your browser may still serve you an old old result and not the actual stuff that the server sends. I'm guessing a bit though.

Comment: @Michael "Model-View-Controller Controller"